# fatal: no pg_hba.conf entry for host when trying to connect to a redshift database from a new Mac(Catalina)

Tags: r, postgresql, macos-catalina

I recently got a new system where i have been setting up and installing R and RStudio using Homebrew. However, when i try to connect to my redshift database from RStudio I keep running into missing pg_hba.conf entry error. I tried locating this file and came across below:

```
(base) ➜  workspace locate pg_hba.conf
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/13.2_1/share/postgresql/pg_hba.conf.sample
/usr/local/share/postgresql/pg_hba.conf.sample
```

not sure if these are the right ones. I installed Rpostgres and RpostgreSQL from R and tried brew install for postgres. None of these seem to be solving the issue. I get the same error. And I tried setting SSL = "require" in the connection statement. But it wont let me manually turn on SSL. I believe its some file missing, or path missing but i have not come across any solutions so far which can help me figure out how to solve this.

Comment: You should read the PostgreSQL documentation on authentication and `pg_hba.conf`.

Comment: Do you have a local redshift database?  I didn't think that was possible, with it exclusively available on "the cloud".  In which case you certainly won't find the pg_hba.conf on your local hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your Mac(Catalina) IP in pg_hba.conf file present on machine hosting redshift database. Else you need to allow all connections to redshift database by adding below line

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            trust
```

Also, you need to change listen_addresses = 'localhost' to listen_addresses = '*' in your postgresql.conf file.

After that restart the database services and hopefully it will work fine.